# How can I run a function several times continuously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

All I'm trying to do is making a winking box. In other word I want to call a function into itself. I have this function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click to fade in/out box</button><br /><br /><br />
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

I want when user clicks on the button, that box fade in/out several time continuously as long as the time a request *(ajax)* takes. Currently when user clicks on the button, that box fades in/out *once*. Now I want to start fading in/out until a request ends. How can I do that?

Actually I'm trying to make a **blinking** box when a request is sending.

Comment: set a variable when the ajax request is first send, then run a function that checks that variable. unset the variable when the ajax request receives a response.

Comment: @Polyov First of all I need to make a box which blinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function toggleForever() {
    $("#div1").fadeToggle("slow", toggleForever);
  }
  
  $("button#start").click(function () {
    toggleForever();
  });
  
  $("button#stop").click(function () {
    $("#div1").stop().animate({opacity:1}, "slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Click to fade in/out box</button>
<button id="stop">Click to stop</button><br /><br /><br />
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

The function parameter to `fadeToggle` gets called when the animation is complete. On another button click, we `stop` the animation and fade the box in (so it's always visible when we're done, no matter where in the animation we were). In your real code, you'll do that when your AJAX call is complete.

**UPDATE**

Another approach, using CSS animations instead. One notable difference here is stopping the animation moves abruptly back to full opacity.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#start').click(function () {
    $('#div1').addClass('blinking');
  });
  
  $('#stop').click(function () {
    $('#div1').removeClass('blinking');
  });
});
```

```css
.blinking {
  animation: blinker 600ms linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes blinker { to { opacity: 0; } }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Click to fade in/out box</button>
<button id="stop">Click to stop</button><br /><br /><br />
<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

Comment: great, upvote ..just it has a problem. if the box is hidden and I press `Click to stop` button, then that box will remain hidden .. I never want that box be hidden forever.

Comment: So when the animation is over, you want the box to be visible?

Comment: Won't work .. when the box is visible and you press `Click to stop` button, it ends up with a hidden box.

Comment: @stack I'm having trouble reproducing it, but at least once I think the box has remained hidden when I hit the button just as it has finished fading out. I haven't been able to reproduce the behavior you describe. Give me a few minutes to read up on jQuery animations.

Comment: Well thanks for spending your time to solve my problem. Also as a note, I guess `done` variable is useless anymore.

Comment: @stack Well, I have no explanation for why, but the code in my latest edit seems to work reliably. It's doing an explicit animation on opacity rather than using `fadeIn`.

Comment: Just for my information, isn't is possible to improve the  code and make a object named `blink`. And use it like this `blink.start()`, `blink.stop()` or something similar? Actually I need to use that function for multiple different elements. That's why I insist on putting `$("#div1").stop().animate({opacity:1}, "slow");` into that function.

Comment: @stack Sure, that should be easy to do. See also my latest update, which moves all the blinking to a CSS class. That should also make it easy to reuse.

Comment: Your updated version is fine, but not as good as the previous one *(at least for me)*. Because the most of my website's user use old browsers like IE7 `:-)` .. So I cannot use CSS3 codes `:-(`

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery there are some global ajax events.

You may listen for [ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/), [ajaxComplete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) like in:

```
    $(function () {
        $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
            // Start your animation
        });
        $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
            // End your animation
        });
    });
```

My snippet:

```js
// utility function to wait (simulate ajax)
$.wait = function(ms) {
  var defer = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() { defer.resolve(); }, ms);
  return defer;
};


var isAjaxEnded = true;

$(function () {
  $("#div1").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeToggle("slow", function() {
      if (!isAjaxEnded)
        $("#div1").trigger('click');
    });
  });

  $( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    isAjaxEnded = false;
    $("#div1").trigger('click');
  });
  
  $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
    // the next line is commented because I'm simulating...
    //isAjaxEnded = true;
    // End your animation
  });
  
  
  $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/users').done(function(data) {
    // just wait only 3 seconds
    $.wait(3000).then(function() {
      isAjaxEnded = true;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" style="width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetInterval to run the on off cycle continuously and end it with ClearInterval.

```
var _timer1;
var _timer2;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#BtnStart").click(function(){
        _timer1 = setInterval(function(){ $("#div1").fadeToggle("slow"); }, 500);       
        _timer2 = setInterval(function(){ $("#div1").fadeToggle("slow"); }, 1000);
    });     

    //Call stop stop annimation
    $("#BtnStop").click(function(){
        clearInterval(_timer1);
        clearInterval(_timer2);
    });     

});
```